# Limit association based on rich relation attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, slim-lang

first question for me here! Im trying to assign 'key companies' to my users. These are found in a `many-to-many` rich join table. On this table there are attributes like `new`, `key`, `active` and so forth. I want to assign companies to users in a long list and for that Im using `SimpleForm`.

Everything is working excepts that I want to filter out and limit the association relation based on the attributes on the rich relation. I have company relations for each user but not all of them are a`key`-relation or a `new`-relation for example. I only want the association being `key` to show up and not touch the other ones. I also want to set the attribute `active` to `true` when Im assigning these companies to the users. My code looks like this now:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :company_user_relationships
    has_many :companies, through: :company_user_relationships
```

**company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :company_user_relationships
    has_many :users, through: :company_user_relationships
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "company_user_relationships", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.boolean  "key"
  t.boolean  "active"
  t.datetime "last_contacted"
  t.string   "status_comment"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "status"
  t.boolean  "new"
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def assign_key_companies
    User.update(params[:users].keys, params[:users].values)
    redirect_to(:back)
end
```

**view**

```
= form_for :user_companies,
        url: assign_key_companies_users_path,
        html: {:method => :put} do |f|
  - users.each do |user|
    = simple_fields_for "users[]", user do |u|
      tr
        td.col-md-4
          = "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
        td.col-md-8
          = u.association :companies, label: false, collection: @key_company_candidates,
                      input_html: {data: {placeholder: " Assign key companies"}, class: 'chosen-select'}
  = submit_tag "Save key companies", class: "btn btn-success pull-right"
```

I basically want to only show `user.companies.where(key: true)` and the SQL`COMMIT` to always put the `key`-field to `true` when updating the record.

How can i filter out to only affect the associations I want?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways.

First to filter it at the association level

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :company_user_relationships, -> { where("company_user_relationships.key" => true) }
```

Or a where

```
user.companies.where("company_user_relationships.key" => true)
```

When you call `user.companies` it actually doing the join table among all three tables, so you could specify the condition like my example.

Comment: Thank you! I found a way to add another has_many relation that only showed key relationships, kinda like the first example you showed. Through rails magic it then set all the properties for me automatically when i mass assigned them :)